# Not able to clear Html Elements from document fragment

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, memory-leaks, jquery-blockui

While investigating a memory leak in IE11, using the developer tools I found some DOM Detach elements.
After doing further investigation, inside I found Document fragment sections where some HTML nodes were still retaining memory and not being garbage collected.

Here's code from the BlockUI plugin

```
var s = "Some Div tags"
var lyr2 = $(s);
```

`$()` is adding in document fragment
I am using jquery 1.7.2 version, assistance appreciated

Please find line numbers .
https://github.com/malsup/blockui/blob/master/jquery.blockUI.js#L293-L326

Comment: Always declare variables with var to avoid they going to the global namespace. also try to use a self invoking function to avoid the global namespace.

Comment: var s = "Some Div tags"
var lyr2 = $(s); did the same but still issue presist